# Is there a way to log third party modules to a specific instance a class and file handler using Python logging module?

Tags: python-3.x, jenkins, python-logging

I am working with python-jenkins and other third party modules in a project. I currently have a Main and a Logger class. Main class initializes with an id that gets passed to instance of Logger class which setups stream and file handlers associated to those logger and main instances. I need to enable separate debugging capabilities for each instance of Main class but what I am getting are logs associated to urllib (python-jenkins) and other third party modules leaking into both of the instances of Main's filehandlers that I have created. An example of the log file associated to 'env1' would be:

```
DEBUG: 2024-01-30 10:47:40,348 | connectionpool | _new_conn | Starting new HTTP connection (1): jenkins-env1.cloud.org:80
DEBUG: 2024-01-30 10:47:40,364 | connectionpool | _make_request | http://jenkins-env1.cloud.org:80 "GET /api/json HTTP/1.1" 200 10121
DEBUG: 2024-01-30 10:47:40,370 | connectionpool | _new_conn | Starting new HTTP connection (2): jenkins-env1.cloud.org:80
DEBUG: 2024-01-30 10:47:40,491 | connectionpool | _make_request | http://jenkins-env1.cloud.org:80 "GET /api/json HTTP/1.1" 200 10121
DEBUG: 2024-01-30 10:47:40,603 | connectionpool | _make_request | http://jenkins-env1.cloud.org:80 "GET /crumbIssuer/api/json HTTP/1.1" 200 155
DEBUG: 2024-01-30 10:47:40,714 | connectionpool | _make_request | http://jenkins-env1.cloud.org:80 "GET /me/api/json?depth=0 HTTP/1.1" 200 406
DEBUG: 2024-01-30 10:47:41,076 | connectionpool | _make_request | http://jenkins-env1.cloud.org:80 "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 None
DEBUG: 2024-01-30 10:47:41,255 | logger_instance_test | debug | Logged in from http://jenkins-env1.cloud.org
DEBUG: 2024-01-30 10:47:41,262 | connectionpool | _new_conn | Starting new HTTP connection (1): jenkins-env2.cloud.org:80
DEBUG: 2024-01-30 10:47:41,275 | connectionpool | _make_request | http://jenkins-env2.cloud.org:80 "GET /api/json HTTP/1.1" 200 9407
DEBUG: 2024-01-30 10:47:41,279 | connectionpool | _new_conn | Starting new HTTP connection (2): jenkins-env2.cloud.org:80
DEBUG: 2024-01-30 10:47:41,396 | connectionpool | _make_request | http://jenkins-env2.cloud.org:80 "GET /api/json HTTP/1.1" 200 9407
DEBUG: 2024-01-30 10:47:41,505 | connectionpool | _make_request | http://jenkins-env2.cloud.org:80 "GET /crumbIssuer/api/json HTTP/1.1" 200 154
DEBUG: 2024-01-30 10:47:41,615 | connectionpool | _make_request | http://jenkins-env2.cloud.org:80 "GET /me/api/json?depth=0 HTTP/1.1" 200 408
DEBUG: 2024-01-30 10:47:42,097 | connectionpool | _make_request | http://jenkins-env2.cloud.org:80 "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 None
```

Hopefully the logs are clear but as you can see if I open the log file associated to 'env1' instance I would get the following mixed records of both 'env1' and 'env2' connections to jenkins which is not what I want. I want urllib connectionpool logs of 'env1' separate to those of 'env2'. I can only achieve this with logs in my Main class but not third party logs. What am I missing? Here is the code that I am currently using:

```
import os, logging, uuid, glob
from datetime import datetime
import jenkins

FORMAT = '%(levelname)s: %(asctime)s | %(module)s | %(funcName)s | %(message)s'
LOGS_LIMIT = 10
juser = os.environ['JENKINS_USER'] # Jenkins username
env1 = os.environ['ENV1_TOKEN']
env2 = os.environ['ENV2_TOKEN']


class Logger:

    def __init__(self, id) -> None:
        self.level=logging.DEBUG
        self.logger = self.get_logger(id)
        self.logger.setLevel(self.level) 

    def get_logger(self, id):
        return logging.getLogger(id)
    
    def setup_logger(self, pipeline_name) -> str:
        logs_dir = 'logs_dir'

        if not os.path.exists(logs_dir):
            os.makedirs(logs_dir, 0o777)

        else:
            logs = glob.glob(f'{logs_dir}/*.log')
            sorted_logs = sorted(logs, key=os.path.getmtime)

            if len(logs) >= LOGS_LIMIT and sorted_logs:
                oldest = sorted_logs[0]
                os.remove(oldest)

        console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
        console_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        formatter = logging.Formatter(FORMAT)
        console_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        self.logger.addHandler(console_handler)

        fn = pipeline_name + '-' + datetime.now().strftime("%b-%d-%Y_%I-%M-%S-%p") + '.log'
        fn_path = os.path.join(logs_dir, fn)
        fh = logging.FileHandler(fn_path)
        formatter = logging.Formatter(FORMAT)
        fh.setLevel(self.level)
        fh.setFormatter(formatter)       
        self.logger.addHandler(fh)

        urllib = logging.getLogger('urllib3.connectionpool')
        urllib.setLevel(self.level)
        urllib.addHandler(fh)

    def debug(self, message) -> None:
        return self.logger.debug(message)

class Main:
    def __init__(self, user, password, env) -> None:
        self.juser = user
        self.jpass = password
        self.env = env
        self.id = str(uuid.uuid4())[:8]

        self.logger = Logger(self.id)
        self.logger.setup_logger(f'{self.env}-{self.id}')

    def connect(self):
        self.jendpoint = f'http://jenkins-{self.env}.cloud.org'
        self.jserver = jenkins.Jenkins(self.jendpoint, username=self.juser, password=self.jpass, timeout=20)
        self.jwho = self.jserver.get_whoami()
        self.jversion = self.jserver.get_version()

        self.logger.debug(f'Logged in from {self.jendpoint}')

def main():
    instance1 = Main(juser, env1, 'env1')
    instance1.connect()
    instance2 = Main(juser, env2, 'env2')
    instance2.connect()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am new to python logging and I know I have a lot to learn still. Any help, comments or questions are greatly appreciated. Thank you.